# Change a class name and call a new function

Tags: jquery

I need to remove a class and change its name to another name in jQuery and need to run a method for the new class name.

My divs are here

```
<!-- Drag and Drop Area Start -->
<div class="tile instruments">
<div>

<article id="content">
<div id="drop-area" style="border: solid 1px; width: 100%; height: 800px;"> 
</div>
</article>
<!-- End -->
```

I have a div called instruments as the class name
I need to change that class name to inst, when fire my first jQuery function 
then when I press the new added div It need to say hello.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    $(".inst").click(function(){
            alert("Hello");
        });

    $(".instruments").click(function(){
            $("#drop-area").append($(this));
            console.log($(this).attr('class'));
            $(this).removeClass("instruments");
            console.log($(this).attr('class'));
            $(this).addClass("inst");
            console.log($(this).attr('class'));
        });


 });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unbind the first event handler when it is triggered, otherwise it will be triggered again when you click on the element again. You can use the [`one` method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to automatically unbind the event handler.

Just bind the other event handler to the element in the first event handler:

```
$(".instruments").one("click", function(){
  $("#drop-area").append($(this));
  console.log($(this).attr('class'));
  $(this).removeClass("instruments");
  console.log($(this).attr('class'));
  $(this).addClass("inst");
  console.log($(this).attr('class'));
  $(this).click(function(){
    alert("Hello");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using event delegation in order to select the dynamically added element:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".inst", function() {
        alert("Hello");
    });
```

Comment: for your way both methods are calling at a same time, my problem is only first one method only to be run what am i do?